# How can I use AspectJ to print call hierarchy for a method?

Tags: java, aspectj

My objective is to find out in a big project where a few particular API methods are being called and in what fashion.

e.g. given two methods say `com.pack.API.x()` and `com.pack.API.y()`

I would like to know when they are called, what is the call hierarchy at the time of call and what arguments were used?

I am using AspectJ but it can only tell me at the point where the method is called, not the complete call hierarchy. here is a sample pointcut and advice I wrote:

```
import org.aspectj.lang.Signature;

public aspect TraceXCut {

pointcut xCall() : (call(* com.pack.API.x(..)) && !cflow(within(TraceXCut)));

before() : xCall() {
    Signature sig = thisJoinPointStaticPart.getSignature();
    String line = "" + thisJoinPointStaticPart.getSourceLocation().getLine();
    String sourceName = thisJoinPointStaticPart.getSourceLocation().getWithinType().getCanonicalName();
    System.out.println("Call from " +  sourceName + " line " + line
                       + " to " +sig.getDeclaringTypeName() + "." + sig.getName());
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the start of the methods, why not just use something like:

```
new Exception().printStackTrace();
```

If you don't actually throw the Exception, your code will continue as normal. As for the arguments, you can print those as well.

Comment: Thanks, simple and effective :)